# How to $filter appRoleAssignments based on appRoleId?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have an enterprise application registered in Azure AD Tenant. It contains certain **appRoles** which have been assigned to Azure AD Users. Now, I would like to fetch all the users having some specific **appRoles**.

I have tried this:
`GET /servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignedTo`
taken from here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters

It seems like I am able to fetch all the appRoleAssignments successfully using this API, but whenever I put a filter such as: `appRoleId eq {app-role-id}` I am geting error like:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause appRoleId: System.Guid",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-10-25T16:33:41",
            "request-id": "{request-id}",
            "client-request-id": "{client-request-id}"
        }
    }
}
```

And whenever I put single quotes, like `appRoleId eq '{app-role-id}'`, I get this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-10-25T16:34:30",
            "request-id": "{request-id}",
            "client-request-id": "{client-request-id}"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with both **v1** and **beta** endpoint. So how do I filter on **appRoleId**?

Comment: Could you share the whole request including the $filter query?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Microsoft Graph does not support the **$filter** on **appRoleId** yet. They already have an open issue:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/990

There is also a feature request here which we can upvote: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/application-api-add-support-for-filtering-approleassignment-by/idi-p/2433822

Also in the Doc, **$filter** is only provided on **principalDisplayName** and **resourceId**

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVD8Y.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4Efg.png)